# Hosting website (form) on GitHub or Dropbox?

Tags: forms, github, dropbox, contacts

Forgive me if I sound gibberish. I use coding as my hobby in my free time (Non IT professional) and thinking to release a website on GitHub or Dropbox.

However, I guess these support The websites that are static in nature. The website which I am developing has form which is crucial where users will fill the details and click on submit in order to get the data.

Now before I dive into paid service of hosting, I would like to first begin with testing stage or host the website for free by using GitHub or so until I get confidence.

So my question- is it possible to run the website that has forms such contact name , number, address etc on GitHub or Dropbox?

Any answer or help, comments, suggestions is much appreciated. Alternative to GitHub are also welcome ( links leading on how to release would be helpful).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about Dropbox, but GitHub allows you to host static sites only.

Comment: I'm not a big user, but I often come across others using heroku or google app engine. Both are free until a certain limit

Comment: @ Anton SiziKov @Sundeep thanks for your comments. I shall look out accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about hosting a website on Github and dropbox is really a good option or not. However as you are in starting face and you do not have any specific requirements like space and bandwidth and all I would not stop you to host your website on dropbox and github and it is free, you dont have to pay anything. for more information on it [click here](https://alexcican.com/post/guide-hosting-website-dropbox-github/)

I have another two options for you in which you might be interested.

(1) [Heroku](https://signup.heroku.com/login) is one of the most popular platform for hosting your web-site or web-application. You can get up to 5 repositories free on basic account. I think you do not require any database but just in case if you do in future they do provide postgresql. You might find Little-bit challenging in starting for hosting on it as you are not IT professional however you will eventually start learning.

for more information on heroku [click here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby)

(2) you can host your website on [freehosting](https://www.freehosting.com/) which is free for 1 year and they provide 2 GB space for your website as you have static page I am sure it wont increase more than that. On top of that they do provide one MySql database too which in case you need.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a Ton  You have provided very useful information. By the way, does these websites such as Heroku- Do they accept forms kind of websites? I hope you understood my question or let me put in another way- I have created a html page that contains Forms. So when a user fills the form and click on "Submit" ,it gets saved on the file. Does this kind work?

Comment: Yes I they do accept dynamic website in which user can fill the data and your model part which is database can store those data. @Rookie_Coder